# How to enable tasks in bulk

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0

I have many tasks in Windows task library.
I need to enable them at one go.

Right now I have to do it individually which is not a feasible solution.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
$task_name="Imported Task"
$task_path="\myTasks\"
Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task_name -TaskPath $task_path
```

I searched google but of no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the scheduler com object :

```
$computername="localhost"
$sch = New-Object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")   
$sch.connect($computername)
$root=$sch.GetFolder("\") 
$folder =$sch.GetFolder("\myTasks") 
$folder.GetTasks(0) |%{$_.enabled=$true}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*-ScheduledTask` cmdlets are only available in Windows 8/Server 2012 and newer (in which case you should have PowerShell v4, not v2). If you have Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 you could do this:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\myTasks' | Enable-ScheduledTask
```

otherwise use [@Kayasax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32579357/1630171)'s suggestion.